# Restify refusing POST/PUT requests after 10 requests

Tags: node.js, curl, restify

I've built a small API using Restify and Node.js. I have a PHP application sending cURL requests, but after **five** PUT or POST requests (10 when using CLI), the Node.js server starts refusing PUT and POST requests (but not GET requests, and I haven't tried DELETE yet) from the client that sent them.

How do I prevent this from happening? I don't want to have to restart my server every few seconds.

Comment: Sounds like your PUT/POST handlers are hitting some sort of connection pool limit (but without any code I can only guess...).

Comment: @robertklep what kind of code would you need? code from my PHP cURL requests, or code from my server?

Comment: @robertklep eesh, this is embarrassing; i was forgetting to close the MySQL connections after running everything, and my connection pool limit was 10 (the script ran two requests, that's why i thought it failed after five). if you hadn't said anything about the connection pool, i probably wouldn't have thought to check that. thanks!

Comment: I would just add that the reason for 5 vs 10 requests is that browsers were likely sending an OPTIONS request prior to the actual PUT/POST.